# How does Bitbucket or GitHub save the repositories?

Tags: github, git

I'm asking this question because in my office we are about to migrate all our Repos from SVN to GIT. And we are trying to find which one will be the best option. We want to get GitHub or BitBucket because they are free.

The advantage of BitBucket is that they let you make repositories private (Very Important for us), but we want to know what is stored on the server. Just the change that we made on the code, or also the code itself. If the code is saved on the server, we are needing some GUI of Git that doesn't store the code.

(In the office they are very protective of the Code).

Comment: If you question will be closed, maybe you can retry to re-open it on webapps.stackexchange.com .

Comment: `but we want to know what is stored on the server. Just the change that we made on the code` - This question makes me think you may need to go back and spend some more time learning how GIT and other version control systems work. `we are needing some GUI of Git that doesn't store the code.` - That simply does not make any sense at all.  You seem to be asking for an apple to not be an apple.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your whole code will be stored on their server.
If someone compromises those services or steals your password/keys, they have access to the code (including all historical changes you made).

If this is not acceptable because your company does not want their code to leave their offices, then you need to run your own git server in house.